# Pentaho passing variable from modified java script value to table input

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I need to passing variable from modified java script value and pass it to table input query

this is my 
[image]

If i click preview the output

```
initator_reference | a | ''   |
1                  | a | null |
2                  | a | null |
3                  | a | null |
4                  | a | null |
```

It shouldnt be null but "testing" string on that third field
and dont ask me why i put that variable in select, its just for testing before i put it in "where condition=variable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Table Input** supports two different ways of making the SQL dynamic: Variable Substitution and inserting data from an incoming stream.

**Variable substitution**

This is what you currently have configured in the Table Input: You put ${variable} somewhere and when the step **initializes**, the value is pasted as text into the SQL.

Because all the steps initialize at the same time in a transformation, your Javascript step has not had time to set the value. In PDI you **cannot set and use a variable** within the same transformation.

**Insert data from step**

The second way is used by selecting a source step in the "Insert data from step" option in the Table input. In this mode, the Table Input takes a row from the selected step and inserts fields (in order) into the SQL at question marks (?) you insert. Normally it expects a single row, but you can choose to execute for EACH row.

This way should work for your scenario:

1. Put a Generate Rows step at the start and set it to generate 1 row.
2. Connect it to the Javascript step.
3. In the Javascript step, specify the return variable as an output field in the bottom grid, it will get added to the stream.
4. In the Table Input, select the Javascript step at "Insert data from step"
5. In your SQL, insert ? at the position of the variable. You may need single quotes around it if the value is a string: WHERE column = '?'.
6. Preview the transformation to see the result, the Table Input's preview is disabled because of the dependency.

Notes:

- Step 1 and 2 may not be needed, I'm not sure if the JS step generates a row by itself. I like to be explicit about that, often naming the Generate Rows step "Generate 1 row".
- If you have an existing stream or multiple fields to insert, you can use a Select Values step to put the fields in the order they need to be inserted into the SQL.

Comment: already done your step but its error on table input
,see my answer section for the picture(second picture)

Comment: @AlexanderChandra: In your second picture, I see no quotes around the ? in your table input. You're probably getting an error "unknown column ...". Try single quotes.

Comment: How can we replace a variable with comma-separated strings to run a query like where a column in (?). I tried sending this string to the Table Input but the replace doesn't compute the? inside the parenthesis. I tried concatenating () around by string and then send directly to ? in the table input but that doesn't work as well because PDI adds "" it to be like "(myCommaSeparatedStrings)" and this my query fails.

Comment: @Navroop That's almost a new question rather than a comment. The ? insertion only works for simple strings due to escaping, as you've seen. If you need a variable  number of values in the where clause, you'll probably have more luck constructing a custom SQL statement and using the SQL step.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found the solution myself 
The First Step is Modified java script value->set variables
and then get variable->table input(check replace variable in script) and you just need to place "?" to your query (this "?" string is your variable, i dont know if there any other way to call variable)
[image]

and as reminder javascript on pentaho is a bit different with real javascript
[image]

Comment: Maybe they've changed something in later versions, bu from my experience, this shouldn't work. From what I know, the JS step shouldn't be processed at all, if it has no input. And Get Variable step should be processed in parallel with JS and Set Variables steps. Are you sure, that the value, which comes is the one set in JS step? It is not just a default value, set in Get Variables step or in the ktr properties? And the value from JS is being picked up one the first run of ktr after Spoon is restarted?

Comment: well i just found the problem, for first time i run preview it show today date - 10 (my javascript) then i change my javascript to today-8 and its still show today-10. Do you have a solution?

Comment: The approach, suggested by @Cyrus should work. Basically, you need to put a single row input to JS step (you can use Detect empty stream step for it: it does not generate columns, so you will not need to remove them), then place your Table input instead of your Set variables step and replace 'Input data from step' to point to JS step. And finally remove Set/Get variable steps. It should work.