# Parameter INTEGER in Table Input

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have one job and two transformations.
In first transformation I have Table input where I get max(id) from table.
Next I copy rows to result -> Write to log -> Set Variables.
In Set Variables I have Field name = max_id and variable name = max_id.

In second transformation I have Get Variables with name = max_id and Variable = ${max_id} and Type = Integer  -> Write to log

Next I have Table input =

```
   select id AS CCOLUMNS from REPO.dbo.STATUS with (nolock)
   where id = ${max_id}
```

I get in log:

```
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - offending row : [max_id Integer(9)]
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Error setting value #1 [Integer(9)] on prepared statement
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - The index 1 is out of range.
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getQueryFieldsFallback(Database.java:2354)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getQueryFields(Database.java:2193)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInputMeta.getFields(TableInputMeta.java:253)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  ... 9 more
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - offending row : [max_id Integer(9)]
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Error setting value #1 [Integer(9)] on prepared statement
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - The index 1 is out of range.
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1076)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getQueryFieldsFallback(Database.java:2328)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  ... 11 more
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Error setting value #1 [Integer(9)] on prepared statement
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - The index 1 is out of range.
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - 
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:5165)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValue(Database.java:1058)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1074)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  ... 12 more
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 - Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:919)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setNull(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1491)
  2019/09/11 15:21:33 - Merge Join.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:5052)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you configure the Table Input step to make use of incoming fields from the stream by specifying a step in "Insert data from step". That's not needed when you use named variables (and variable substitution).

Manually clear the step name from that and you should be good to go.

For more detailed info, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43651035/6803853